# Is there a way of Creating lnk file using javascript mslink.sh

Tags: javascript

As per this link 
[Is there a way of Creating lnk file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622018/is-there-a-way-of-creating-lnk-file-using-javascript)
I am trying to create a .lnk file.
I would like to know how to set the property Start In, which is a folder location of the .lnk file 
and also the .lnk file that I am trying to create has additional parameters in the Target property.

Ex : Expected .lnk file properties

Target : "C:\Windows\System32\Calc.exe" /mode:QWE /role:Admin

Start In : C:\Windows\System32\

[Is there a way of Creating lnk file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622018/is-there-a-way-of-creating-lnk-file-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WScript.Shell function `CreateShortcut`

```
var objShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
var lnk = objShell.CreateShortcut("C:\\my_shortcut.lnk")

lnk.TargetPath = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\Calc.exe";
lnk.Arguments = "/mode:QWE /role:Admin";
lnk.Description = "Your description here...";
lnk.IconLocation = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\Calc.exe, 0";
lnk.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Windows\\System32";
lnk.Save();
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks  for the response .I am looking for a way to do this in JavaScript. Can you please suggest?

Comment: My answer is Javascript. You can run this code from the command line with cscript.exe.

Comment: Hello, I am not able to create .lnk file using the above code when I Deploy the code to the server. I believe the working directory is not set or do I need to change any config in the IE?

Comment: @DeepakM So this is for ASP? I'm not too familiar with that. This script will work with a command prompt. Maybe you need to change the web server's permissions? You should probably ask a new question to get help with that.

Comment: Hello Johnny, this is not for asp.  it's with JavaScript. Though the file gets created locally in the ide when executed , it's fails to get created when deployed on the server. I tried to replicate the same in the ide and I could replicate it by not setting the working directory. Also tried to debug and I could see it is being set and also I tried to set the current directory to the exe file location. No luck. Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Hello Johnny, I tried to change a bit and launch the exe file with parameters using the .exec and .run method of activex . Again it works on the http local server and not in the https webserver . Do I need to change any settings in the browser ? Please let me know. Even if I try to create a .lnk file as suggested by you ,while launching the lnk with .run method ,it's not working .