# Safari browser issue with downloading image file with javascript

Tags: javascript, download, safari

I am trying to download png image with javascript.

**Problem:**

First it downloads image actually opens up in a new tab for user download,but after that whenever i click to download it doesnt downloading anything.
But it works fine on other browser, issue with **safari** only.

**Below what i have tried so far:**

```
        imgData  = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('download', projectName+'.png');
        link.setAttribute('target', "_blank");
        link.setAttribute('href', imgData);
        link.click();
        link.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no download attribute for a tag in safari

You can use FileSaver.js library. [See how to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997057/how-to-use-filesaver-js)

another method:
You can do form submit this works only if content-disposition and content-type header present in response headers

For example:

```
$('body').append('<from id="fileDownload" action="< URL to download >" method="< HTTP method >" </form>');
```

$('#fileDownload').submit();
$('#fileDownload').remove();