# Export 100000 rows to CSV in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 100 000 lines and i want to export them to CSV, i did manage to export it for few lines but many thousands of lines return network error to my browser and i cannot download it.

```
        let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
        csvContent += [
            Object.keys(payload[0]).join(";"),
            ...payload.map(item => Object.values(item).join(";"))
        ]
            .join("\n")
            .replace(/(^\[)|(\]$)/gm, "");

        const data = encodeURI(csvContent);
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", data);
        link.setAttribute("download", "export.csv");
        link.click();
```

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: I think you have to work with `wait time out to take back response from server`

Comment: Possibly this solution, using a Blob, might help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35251739/11683772

Comment: it does not show an error but it does not download it, i think because javascript cannot handle that amount of data ?

Comment: that code runs on server or in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) with 100000 rows

Use [FileSaver.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25186103/985399)

```
var blob = new Blob([csvContent], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "export.csv");
```

Maybe also split the string with [`Blob.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice) and save several chunks.