# Angular FileSaver.JS change downloaded file name

Tags: javascript, angular, filesaver.js

I am using Angular and FileSaver to save a file but I want to specify a name to the downloaded file

```
this._UsersService.downloadReport(id).subscribe(data => {
  FileSaver.saveAs(data);
});
```

Comment: Read the documentation? `FileSaver saveAs(Blob/File/Url, optional DOMString filename, optional Object { autoBom })`. The second argument is the file name

Answer (score 2):

Not too familiar with it, but wouldn't you just add a file name option after your data?

ex: `FileSaver.saveAs(data, "my filename")` ?

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Edit: perhaps another relevant SO post: [How to use filesaver.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997057/how-to-use-filesaver-js)